# Force cache update Wygwam / Change timestamp

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, cache, ckeditor

I was finally able to update Wygwam to the latest version (3.3.3).

One user has contacted me to tell me he only saw gray fields instead of the normal Wygwam fields.

I told him to empty his brower's cache, which worked. I would like to force to update the cache for Wygwam for all users so they don't have to do a thing. (And don't contact me because they are panicking ;) )

I tried placing CKEDITOR.timestamp = '1.0'; in config.js, but than I get an error in the console: illegal character.

Can someone tell me how to force updating the cache in Wygwam?

Answer (score 0):

I found where to add a timestamp.

After this code on line 530 in helper.php:

```
self::include_theme_js('lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
```

Place this line of code:

```
self::insert_js('CKEDITOR.timestamp="1.0";');
```

The files config.js, styles.js and [your-language].js are now loaded with the new timestamp. But changed code in config.js will not load in the browser. So if anyone has ideas on this, please let me know.